# Read set of numbers from txt file

Tags: actionscript-3, file, numbers, text-files

I've been working on a project for a while but got stuck where I have a text file that contains a set of numbers in this format:

```
1-2-3-4
1-2-3-4
1-2-3-4
1-2-3-4
```

So I must read the numbers from the file and put them in an array according to the column so at the end I have

```
column1:Array (1,1,1,1) 
column2:Array (2,2,2,2)
```

..... and so on. I can't figure how to do this.

What I managed to do was read all the file and have all the numbers in 1 array but just that.

Here's the code

```
var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
var txtArray:Array;

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest(inputFile.text));

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    txtArray = e.target.data.split(/\-|\n/g);
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding a tag to your question that will indicate the programming language.

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate programming language

Comment: its probably javascript looking at the sample, unless I'm missing something bad.

Comment: @Jon that's definitely not Javascript.

Comment: Why do people ask and go away?

Comment: So do we know what language this is? It should be put in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `split \n \r` to array (reading with a loop)

and the same with... -

a loop in loop to get a multidimensional array

in mind the result is a "table"

finally to get a result do this.

```
variable[file][column]
a[2][3] ----> 4
```

;)

Comment: Thanks its no quit how you told me but the a loop in loop idea helped me.

Comment: thanks! D-Mx, it is difficult to write an real-functional example without a particular language

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting it into two parts, first by line, then by element:

```
function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    preArray:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/g);
    txtArray = new Array();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < preArray.length; i++) {
        txtArray.push(preArray[i].split(/\-/g));
    }
}
```

This will give you a 2D array, which you'd access like this:

```
textArray[0][0]; // result: 1
textArray[2][3];
```

Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Llanis who gave me the idea. This is my final code. Sorry i didn't tag the language it never ocurred to me i'm new.

```
myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest(inputWX.text));

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    txtArray = e.target.data.split(/\-|\n/g);

    var wArray:Array = new Array(txtArray.length/4);
    var xArray:Array = new Array(txtArray.length/4);
    var yArray:Array = new Array(txtArray.length/4);
    var zArray:Array = new Array(txtArray.length/4);

    var a:int = 0;
    var b:int = 0;
    var c:int = 0;
    var d:int = 0;
    var columna:int = 1;

    for(var arrayIndex:int = 0; arrayIndex <= txtArray.length-1;arrayIndex++)
    {
        switch(columna){
            case 1: wArray[a] = txtArray[arrayIndex]; a+=1;
            break;
            case 2: xArray[b] = txtArray[arrayIndex]; b+=1;
            break;
            case 3: yArray[c] = txtArray[arrayIndex]; c+=1;
            break;
            case 4: zArray[d] = txtArray[arrayIndex]; d+=1;
            break;
        }

        if(columna == 4)
            columna = 1;
        else columna++;
    }
```

}